# np.set_printoptions does not work on numpy.ndarray retured by scipy.io.wavfile.read

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, wav

when i read a wav file using scipy.io.wavfile.read and print the numpy.ndarray i only see integers.

i am certain that it should be float values, but i am unable to print them that way.

during my research i discovered, that np.set_printoptions can be used to change the way the data is displayed, but this does not seem to have an effect on the array returned by scipy.io.wavfile.read.

i tried np.set_printoptions, but this does not work.

```
from scipy.io import wavfile as wav
from scipy.fftpack import fft

import numpy as np

np.set_printoptions(precision=4)

rate, data = wav.read('file.wav')

print(data)
```

thank you very much in advance

Comment: *"i am certain that it should be float values..."*  Why are you certain of this?  What is `data.dtype`?

Comment: i have used matlab/octave before and there the values were floats.

data.dtype is int16

Comment: `int16` is 16 bit signed integers.  It is possible that the Octave/Matlab wav reader that you used converted the integer data to floating point automatically.

Comment: You can convert the data with `data.astype(float)`.  `set_printoptions` the underlying datatypes.

Comment: try: np.set_printoptions('nan')

Comment: or np.set_printoptions(threshold = 10000000)#some big number.